# Scan a file from multiple points

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a file `abc.txt` which contains the alphabet printed twice separated by a newline character

```
abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz
```

I would like to create a parser that can parse the lines concurrently. For example one goroutine per line. My current process for trying to do this is:

- Create a channel to receive lines of text
- Create a new scanner for each line
- Pass that scanner and channel to a goroutine
- Process results in the main process

However, only one of the scanners is returning useful output. The code for what I am trying to do is this:

```golang
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("./strangeness/abc.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    inChan := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        var scanner scanner.Scanner
        file.Seek(27, 0)

        scanner.Init(file)

        go parseLine(fmt.Sprintf("Scanner %v:", i), &scanner, inChan)
    }

    for msg := range inChan {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}

func parseLine(name string, scanner *scanner.Scanner, out chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 26; i++ {
        out <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %c", name, scanner.Next())
    }
}
```

I think I may have some misconceptions either about how the go `text/scanner` works or how about files work in general, but I can't track down the actual source of the bug.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166490/how-to-implement-parallel-processing-of-line-based-file-content/58172839#58172839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because of 2 scanner for the file moving the head concurrently.

The desired results can be achieved by creating 2 file handle, each having their own scanner. The following works for me

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/scanner"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    var file [2]*os.File
    var err error
    file[0], err = os.Open("./abc.txt")
    file[1], err = os.Open("./abc.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    defer file[0].Close()
    defer file[1].Close()
    var scanner [2]scanner.Scanner
    inChan := make(chan string)


    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        var n int64 = (int64)(i) * 26
        file[i].Seek(n, 0)

        scanner[i].Init(file[i])
        fmt.Println(scanner[0].Pos)
        go parseLine(fmt.Sprintf("Scanner %v:", i), &scanner[i], inChan)
    }

    for msg := range inChan {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}

func parseLine(name string, scanner *scanner.Scanner, out chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 26; i++ {
        out <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %c", name, scanner.Next())
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    close(out)
}
```

Comment: @BBS : let me know if that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Among the properties a file has is a *single* read position, not one per scanner, per thread, or per goroutine.  When you share a single `os.File` between multiple scanner objects (or anything else), the first one that reads from the file will advance the read pointer for every other scanner.  In your example the first goroutine that runs will read the line from the file, and the second one tries to read but is already at end-of-file.

To make this work you need only one thing reading the file, and you need to ensure that the data you're sending off to goroutines isn't shared (you're not repeatedly reading into a single buffer and sending that same buffer off everywhere, where the next read will overwrite it).

**This is a good time to think about concurrency and if this is actually worth the effort.**  The slowest part of this program, by far, will be actually reading the file from disk, and no amount of goroutines will make that faster.  The extra buffer copy isn't necessary in an optimal single-threaded program, and goroutine synchronization comes with a cost too.  My intuition is that using goroutines here makes the program much more complex and potentially slower.

The core change I'd make to your program is having there only be one thing that reads the file; for instance, a main loop in your program.  The [`bufio`](https://godoc.org/bufio) package includes a [`Scanner`](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner) object that can read a file a line at a time, and produce the copied string.  I would launch a pool of worker goroutines once, and then feed them lines:

```
lines := make(chan string)
file, err := os.Open("./strangeness/abc.txt")
if err != nil { ... }

scan := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scan.Scan() {
    lines <- scan.Text()
}
close(lines)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/o7UwZrgfVy7 has a more complete example that compiles.  Note that the goroutine structure takes some reasoning about: I've launched a separate goroutine to process the results, and have a separate channel to signal its completion.