# How to have multiple goroutines read the lines of a single file?

Tags: go

I want to read a huge file, say > 1 GB, and have its lines processed by multiple worker goroutines.

I'm worried that using a single goroutine (main) for reading the input lines will impose a bottleneck, when using a huge number of worker goroutines.

How can I safely have multiple goroutines read the lines of the file? Is it possible split the input file into several chuncks and have each goroutine operate on a separate chunk individually?

The following is sample code of having one goroutine read input lines with several worker goroutines processing them:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("/path/to/file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    lines := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        // start 100 workers to process input lines.
        // the workers terminate once 'lines' is closed.
        go worker(lines)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    go func() {
        defer close(lines)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }

        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    ...
}
```

Comment: Do the lines need to be processed in order?  That will determine how far you can go with this.   Either way, adding buffering to *lines* can't hurt.   If ordering isn't important, you can add extra processors of lines.  Adding them on the input side is a bit more involved since it involves scanning for delimiters to chunk up the data; but in the abstract you could divide the file into N chunks, and put a scanner on each chunk feeding into lines; and come up with a rule to deal with lines that overlap the chunk boundaries.

Comment: "I'm worried that using a single goroutine (main) for reading the input lines will impose a bottleneck," -- Why are you worried about this? Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Have you actually observed that this is a problem in your case? It probably isn't. Your code looks like it's probably I/O bound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement parallel processing of line-based file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166490/how-to-implement-parallel-processing-of-line-based-file-content)

Comment: @mevets - No, lines don't need to be processed in order.

Comment: @Flimzy - "Your code looks like it's probably I/O bound." - thus, you are also saying that one goroutine reading from the file is insufficient to feed the worker goroutines processing the lines?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it has no sense to read a file concurrently. If you need to perform complex operations on the line data, what you should do is to read the file sequentially and send the content of the lines to each goroutine.

For optimizing this process, you should change different things. The first thing you need to change is the number of workers. This value has not be setted randomly, to achieve the max performance of your computer, use this:

```
for i := 0; i < runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0); i++ {
    go worker(lines)
}
```

With this you will use the CPUs available of you computer effectively.
And finally, to process all the data of each line, you have to add:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer close(lines)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        lines <- scanner.Text()
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()
```

And inside the worker function you will also add a `wg.Done()` at the end.

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you! But what if the goroutine that reads lines from the file cannot read them fast enough to feed the `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)` worker goroutines? Then the program will become I/O-bound.

Comment: Also, isn't it slow to use `sync.WaitGroup` as a counter? Rather, I'd do `wg.Add(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))` and then have the worker goroutines execute `wg.Done()`, when they are about to terminate, because their input channel has been closed.

Comment: "And inside the worker function you will also add a wg.Done() at the end." - should be stated more precise: "... after processing a line".

Comment: With my answer you would follow the worker-consumer paradigm! With the GOMAXPROCS you will use efficiently the cpus of your machine, you will not have problem with your worker goroutines. You need Waitgroup to force your program to process all the lines of the file.

Comment: But in this case there is only a single producer (or worker). What if I don't need to make complex operations on the lines, so that the bottleneck becomes the single producer (file reader). Your answer doesn't address this scenario, does it? You assume the line operations are complex, which they might not be.